# Artist and Album name does not update on iTunes

Tags: itunes, music

On iTunes the artist and album name is shown but after syncing, it says Unknown Artist and Unknown Album on my iPhone. I can see the album art, the lyrics, and the song title.

Why isn't the rest of the information syncing? The sound file is an .mp3. Also, I tried updating my iTunes version from 12.0 to 12.1 but for some reason the installer keeps having problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm led to believe it's Apple's fault as they have discovered that various sources throughout the world download their music via an illegal source (i.e. YouTube to MP3 converters).

If this is the method you use, then no matter how many times you right-click on a song in "My Music", click 'Get Song Info' and enter in the correct song information, iTunes refuses to re-hash the information for your selected song.
Ever since Apple's iTunes 12 overhaul, users who condone third-party download sites have been affected.

The only way people such as you and I can fix this problem is to either purchase our music from the iTunes Store or subscribe to Apple's "Music Genius" promotion -- at a cost of $34.99 annually.

I'll pass, thanks. As for now, I prefer to use my older mobile device to 'drag and drop' .mp3 files -- back when it was oh so much easier!